# How to scrape stats from NBA website with python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape advanced stats from the NBA website, more specifically from this link https://stats.nba.com/leaders/?StatCategory=FG3M&PerMode=Totals. However, I seem to be getting the error  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'. I would appreciate it if someone helped me. Thanks.

## My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://stats.nba.com/leaders/?StatCategory=FG3M&PerMode=Totals'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

columns = ['#', 'PLAYER', 'GP', 'MIN', 'PTS', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG%',  '3PM', '3PA',
        '3P%', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'FT%', 'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK',
        'TOV', 'PF', 'EFF', 'AST/TOV', 'STL/TOV']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
table = soup.find('table').tbody

trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n', '') for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('Stats NBA.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: you can to the find on tbody directly, but first check in soup.text if you actually got the table, which is not guaranteed. Here the find failed to find anything

Comment: `API` is easy https://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?LeagueID=00&PerMode=Totals&Scope=S&Season=2019-20&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StatCategory=FG3M

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(
    'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?LeagueID=00&PerMode=Totals&Scope=S&Season=2019-20&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StatCategory=FG3M').json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r['resultSet']['rowSet'], columns=r['resultSet']['headers'])
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
print('done')
```

View Output Online: [Click Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e5aa13b791b5559425eb74aa1580c80a/output.csv)

> `API` is cool usually.

Answer (score -2):

```
import requests

import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(
    'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?LeagueID=00&PerMode=Totals&Scope=S&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StatCategory=FG3M').json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r['resultSet']['rowSet'], 

columns=r['resultSet']['headers'])

df.to_csv('NBA stats.csv', index=False)

print(df)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: your provided solution is a copy of  αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη's. All you did was change `df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`, to `df.to_csv('NBA stats.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)